# VBA Calling a private function inside of a userform

Tags: vba, forms, excel

I have a userform defined as "SingleListForm".
I have a private sub named "loadSingleListForm(ID As Double)"
I am attempting to pass a variable into the form and I was implementing it in the fashion that loadSingleListForm would set the form up based on ID, basically re-using one form to show variable data from variable sources in the listbox.

But calling a standard Intersect from  outside the form (Worksheet_SelectionChange) these two options compile but do not work.

```
Application.Run "SingleListForm.loadSingleListForm", ID 'ID already declared and assigned
```

[image: VBA runtime error]

This doesn't work either

```
Call ActiveWorkbook.UserForm("SingleListForm").loadSingleListForm(ID)
```

Where it says UserForm I have also tried SingleListForm.
Here the runtime error is:

[image: error2]

I am trying hard not to use a Global Variable here to pass to the form.
Perhaps I should go to Initialize and try something there.
I am trying to pass the variable to the form and then of course set up the form based on this case and then show the form.  you can't pass with show so you have to find another way to set up.

I just realized I have not called a userform private function from outside of the form before, but I do it with modules all the time.  The first case works in that instance.

Cheers,
-WWC

Comment: Have you tried simply `ActiveWorkbook.UserForm("SingleListForm").loadSingleListForm(ID)` without `Call` in front of it?

Comment: Maybe expand the amount of code you have provided: one line doesn't tell us much.  Do you have the form open non-modally while you're navigating around the sheet?  Are there multiple documents open?  Is the userform in the same workbook as the worksheet?

Comment: Well to play around a bit more I moved the function from inside of the userform code to a module, where I know the private call works.  The call works as expected.  But it still leaves me wondering if the userform is like like its own class module why can't you use similar approaches?

Thank you for your quick replies.

The form is the only instance, using only show / hide to bring it up.  SO you can access its variables from outside of the form such as label, caption, and ListBox1.RowSource which are actually the 3 things I set based on ID.  Selection is returned to activecell.

Comment: What I guess I am trying to say is this application of thought works if the private sub is in a module.  Word for Word.  But from inside the userform I am certainly missing something in how to access it.  I am going to test the answer below in a short project as well as the 1st comment.

Comment: BTW - this overcomes the "tiny ass font" issues that excel has with drop down lists.  You can define the Font size and font type of your list box.  SO if you have a list that is a little longer .... pop it into a form listbox so your users can actually see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to do this is to declare a property to the form. In the form's module enter

```
  Option Explicit
  Private myID as double

  Property Set ID(i as double)
     myID = i
  End Property
```

Then your function

```
   Private Sub loadSingleListForm()
     can refer to myID with in it's code
```

To Use this from outside modules you use

```
   Load SingleListForm
   SingleListForm.ID = ID 'ID variable already declared
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your sub in the form as Public `Public Sub loadSingleListForm(ID As Double)` and then call it like this `SingleListForm.loadSingleListForm ID`

Comment: It works this way, thank you.  Also worked moving it to a Module and keeping it private. - WWC

PS - I can't upvote you as I am new to the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Just to cover this.  Empty workbook, one button.
The button calls to a private function in the form that does nothing but open a message box.  Testing concept here.
This is all there is:
[image]

Doesn't work:

```
UserForm1.you_made_it
```

Error at compile, method or data member not found
Same if this:

```
With ThisWorkbook
    UserForm1.you_made_it
  End With
```

Then try this:

```
Application.Run "UserForm1.you_made_it"
```

Error: Cannot run macro . . . .

Try this from first comment:

```
ActiveWorkbook.UserForm("UserForm1").you_made_it
```

Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

So this is the winner from above. Not sure I wanted to go Public but it works.
Doesn't solve how to use a private member in the form but it gets the coding going forward.

```
Public Sub you_made_it()

    MsgBox ("you made it")

End Sub
```

So far:
1) Move the private to a module and then call it
2) make the function Public and it works

Thank you,
-WWC